# Where to store data in Python after split?

Tags: python

I read each line and get array result:

```
arr = line.split("|"); // [1, 500, ABC]
```

Then I need to check of there are a duplications in each line by each value `[1, 500, ABC]`

Which structure of data I have use?

So, if I get two the same lines or line where the first parameter is the same I should skip it:

```
[1, 500, ABC]
[1, 600, ABC] // Skip it
[2, 500, ABC]
[1, 500, ABC] // skip it
```

Comment: You could use a `dict` where the key is the first value of the array. For more advanced cases, consider using `pandas`.

Comment: If I correctly understand, only the first field matters, and you compare all other lines to the first one. Am I right?

Comment: Make a `first_values = set()`, and for each line you can check if it exists `if arr[0] in first_values`, and if not you add the first value `first_values.add(arr[0])`

Comment: You can use a `set`. Also consider reading the file using `csv` and setting `delimiter` to `|`, so you already get the line split at `|`.

Comment: Could I use dict, right? Where the key is the first parameter? And value is?

Comment: @CarlosBergillos: While being a very powerful tool, Pandas is probably overkill here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you want to read a bunch of lines, split them on `|` character, and discard lines where the first field is the same as the first field of the first line. It could be:

```
line = next(file)   # process first line
arr = line.split("|")
field0 = arr[0]
data = [arr[:]]     # make sure to take a copy...
for line in file:
    arr = line.split("|")
    if arr[0] != field0:
        data.append(arr[:])   # again append a copy
```

Comment: What I i need to store row in another list if the first element is duplicated

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm not understanding the question correctly. The part that is confusing me is that if two lines are the same, then it implies the first element is the same. This means that you only need to check for the weaker condition of the first element being the same / observed before?

```
seen_elements = set()
filtered_lines = []
for line in lines:
    arr = line.split("|")
    if arr[0] in seen_elements:
        pass
    else:
        filtered_lines.append(line)
        seen_elements.add(arr[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add that if later you want to quickly identify the elements associated with the first number for some reason, you can also use `dict.setdefault`:

```
seen_items = dict()

for line in lines:
   arr = line.split('|')
   seen_items.setdefault(arr[0], arr[1:])
```